# Why the involution condition is imposed in the definition of integrability?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems

For an $N$-degree-of-freedom system to be integrable, the usual definition imposes the existence of $N$ independent conserved quantities, which must be in involution to each other, i.e.,

$$\{ F_i, F_j \} ~=~ 0\tag{1}$$

Why this extra condition? Why is

$$\{ H, F_i \}~=~0 \tag{2} $$

insufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I) Well, the existence of the involution

$$\{ I_i, I_j \}_{PB} ~=~ 0,\qquad i,j\in\{1, \ldots, n\}.\tag{1}$$

is already generically true locally for a Hamiltonian system, cf. e.g. 
[this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/2451) Phys.SE post. So it 
is essentially only a global/topological requirement in the definition of (Liouville) [integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system).

II) Another possible answer (in light of OP's second equation) is that we would like to write the Hamiltonian $H=H(I_1, \ldots, I_n)$ in terms of the action variables $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ alone [i.e. without the angle variables, which in turn should be *cyclic/ignorable* variables]. Then the involution (1) implies OP's second condition

$$ \dot{I}_i~=~\{ I_i,H \}_{PB} ~=~ 0,\qquad i\in\{1, \ldots, n\}, \tag{2}$$

i.e. that the  action variables $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ are constants of motion [if the system is autonomous and the action variable contain no explicit (but possibly implicit) time dependence]. In other words, a failure of (1) could jeopardize (2).

III) Finally it seems relevant to mention that the involution (1) is the main assumption that goes into the [Caratheodory–Jacobi–Lie theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Lie_theorem), which guarantee that the $n$ actions variables $I_1, \ldots, I_n$ locally can be extended into a full set of $2n$ [Darboux coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem), aka. [canonical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates). See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/2451) related Phys.SE post.