# What does it mean for a system to be integrable?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I am reading this paper: http://aleph.physik.uni-kl.de/~korsch/papers/JPA_24_45.pdf and in section 3 they talk about the [integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system) of the system. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The paper refers to the [notion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system#Hamiltonian_systems_and_Liouville_integrability) of *complete integrability,* aka. *Liouville integrability,*  i.e. the property that there exist $n$ independent globally defined Poisson-commuting [constants of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion). Here $2n$ is the dimension of phase space. In the paper $n=2$. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/2451) related Phys.SE post.