# What does a non-integrable Hamiltonian system mean?

Tags: hamiltonian, integrable-systems

Is it something that cant be solved exactly?
Are there any examples of such system?
Is high-dimension lattice models like Ising model or Hubbard models considered as non-integrable systems?

Comment: Hi. It means that there isn't a canonical transformation which makes the hamilton equation solvable at once( by simple integration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-Integrable systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/)