# Does the Hamilton-Jacobi equation imply that there are always $N$ conserved quantities for any system with $N$ degrees of freedom?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

I'm reviewing the Hamilton-Jacobi equation because I'm working on a research project about Kerr black holes and the geodesics of particles gravitating them (This is not really relevant to the question, but I'm saying it for the sake of context). I was working on the equations of motion and many papers use conserved quantities to integrate the equations and find the geodesics... and they usually use the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism.

In the Hamilton-Jacobi formalism, we find a canonical transformation that transformation that goes from the original hamiltonian $H$ to a new one that is identically zero $\tilde{H}$ such that in the new variables the canonical variables and their momenta are just conserved quantities

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial P}=\dot{Q}=0 \\
\frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial Q}=-\dot{P}=0 .\\
\end{equation}

Then one uses the canonical transformation formalism to find the equation

\begin{equation}
H(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t)+\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=0
\end{equation}

where $S(q,P,t)$ is the generating function. When one solves the equations one finds the original canonical variables as a function of time and $N$ constants of motion $\alpha_i$ which are usually some combination of the new variables $Q$ and $P$.

My question is: **Does this formalism guarantee that for any given system with $N$ degrees of freedom $q_i$ ($i=1,2,\dots N$) that has a hamiltonian that behaves nicely (derivable, etc.) there are always $N$ constants of motion $\alpha_i$?**

If that is so, then I don't understand why such enphasis is put on how conserved quantities are a special thing that systems with symmetries have. I thought that ugly systems with no symmetries are impossible to integrate precisely due to the lack of conserved quantities. **If you can address how the number of conserved quantities relates to integrability that would be awesome**.

Comment: Only integrable systems possess N integrals if motion (independent and in involution). That's their definition.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Then what are those $/alpha_i$ in the solution of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation? That’s the part that’s confusing me.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Integrable vs. Non-Integrable systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/2451)

Comment: I'm not sure what are the $\alpha_i$s as you haven't defined them but I suppose they could be actions in the variable action-angle, so precisely the constants of motion. Again their existence is the definition of integrability.