# Constants of motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, symmetry, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

For any system performing any kind of motion with $n$ degrees of freedom, are $2n-1$ integrals of motion and also $2n$ constants of motion always present? If yes, then is there always a symmetry for each constant? Can the initial conditions be thought as those constants? There are related questions but all have heavy mathematical explanation which I am not aware of yet. Need a theoretical answer

Comment: The keyword is **local vs. global.** Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55861/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44576/2451